# Import Python file [ModuleNotFound]

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook

I'm importing `helpers.py` file from `<project_root>/lib/helpers.py` location to one of the sub-folder in my project. I am using `sys` package. But I'm getting ModuleNotFound error while importing.

Given below is the code I'm using.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/d/Development/s5-data-analysis/lib/')
import helpers
```

The sub-folder is `/d/Development/s5-data-analysis/notebooks/my.ipynb` . What is the correct way of importing this `helper.py` to `my.ipnb`  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to me like you are using Git Bash on Windows (or some other Unix-Windows-Layer), which has its own builtin path translation. Other programs like will only be able to use the usual path names, in this case `d:\Development\s5-data-analysis\lib`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, r"d:\Development\s5-data-analysis\lib")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `lib` folder into a package, by adding `__init__.py` to `lib` folder. In this file, you can import `helpers` module like this:

```
from . import helpers
```

Finally, on your actual codefile, import helpers module like this:

```
from lib import helpers
```

Comment: Still getting the error "ImportError: cannot import name 'helpers'"

Comment: I'm trying to import my Python file to Jupyter notebook

Comment: I like to learn more around creating packages. Thanks for the answer. Feel free to share a useful link with me to learn on creating packages :)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways through which you can import.

**Example 1, Import a python module with python interpreter:**

1.Put this in /home/el/foo/fox.py:

```
def what_does_the_fox_say():
print("vixens cry")
```

2.Get into the python interpreter:

```
 nag@sahil:/home/el/foo$ python
 Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
 >>> import fox
 >>> fox.what_does_the_fox_say()
 vixens cry
 >>>
```

**Example 2, Use execfile or (exec in Python 3) in a script to execute the other python file in place:**

1.Put this in /home/el/foo2/mylib.py:

```
def moobar():
print("hi")
```

2.Put this in /home/el/foo2/main.py:

```
execfile("/home/el/foo2/mylib.py")
moobar()
```

**Example 3. Use from ... import ... functionality:**

1.Put this in /home/el/foo3/chekov.py:

```
def question():
print "where are the nuclear wessels?"
```

2.Put this in /home/el/foo3/main.py:

```
from chekov import question
question()
```